# Check if child object value exists NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm pretty new to C#.  While attempting to set a local variable value, I'm running into a NullReferenceException.
It appears that the `Buyer` object is null, which I'm assuming is why it can't figure out the `Buyer.Username` value.  What I'm not sure about is how to check if `Buyer` is not null AND that the `Buyer.Username` has a non-null value (in the most simple way possible).  Unfortunately, I'm using C# 7.3 which doesn't appear to have support for the `??` operator.

```
BuyerUserName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Transactions[i].Buyer.Username) ? "" : model.Transactions[i].Buyer.Username
```

Comment: Well generally null-coalescing operators like `??` and `?.` reduce to if statements during compile time, so maybe you could just write them yourself? IE `if (Buyer is not null && Buyer.Username is not null)`

Comment: *"if Buyer is not null AND that the Buyer.Username has a non-null value"* - The semantics of that description strongly imply the exact nature of an `if` condition.  What have you tried and what didn't work?  (Also... *"I'm using C# 7.3 which doesn't appear to have support for the ?? operator."* - On what do you base that?)

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. What exactly is stopping you from writing an `if` statement? You know that not everything has to be a one-liner? In fact your one-liner already is hard to read. You sure you want to make it worse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Both `??` and `?.` were introduced in C# 6, so you can use them:

```
BuyerUserName = model.Transactions[i].Buyer?.Username ?? string.Empty;
```

But even without that, there is nothing wrong with taking more than one line to do something, and you could just use an `if` statement:

```
var buyer = model.Transactions[i].Buyer;
if (buyer != null && buyer.Username != null)
    BuyerUserName = buyer.Username;
else
    BuyerUserName = string.Empty;
```

Comment: +1 for saying _"there is nothing wrong with taking more than one line to do something"_.  Too many people seem to think that putting a page of fluent API code into a single statement is a good idea.  Temporary variables cost nothing in your production code (the JITter will nearly always optimize them away in a release build).  What they do is increase debug-ability immensely; you get to see what is null and not-null in the debugger.